# Issue with Progress Indicator Stages in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-progressindicator

I have developed a simple flow to test the Stages in Progress Indicator.
[image]

The issue is that, when I move to second or later stages, the Stage 1 never get marked as completed.

In the screenshot below, I have moved to the third screen. The second Stage is marked as completed but not the first Stage.
[image]

I have verified all the assignment & screen elements and the code of Progress Indicator for Flow is taken directly from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens_stages.htm

Any idea about this issue or any suggestions that can help to troubleshoot this issue.

-Thanks

Comment: did you try this with LWC?

Answer (score 4):

This have been identified as a known issue in Salesforce:
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001U75gQAC

As a workaround, I have inserted an empty anchor element before the lightning:progressIndicator in my FlowStages.cmp:

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if the below steps are followed :-

1. Creation of new resource with resource type as Stage for all the screen.
2. Assignment of Stage value to current stage after each screen.
3. Also, check on the component if the input values currentStage = flow.currentStage and stages = flow.activeStages.